# Operator '===' cannot be applied to types 'number' and 'string .. when used in [ngClass]

Tags: css, angular, typescript, ng-class

I need a div to have a css-class when a variable `cfgSelected` is has a certain value .. here '1' (<- string!!)

```
<div [ngClass]="(cfgSelected ==='1')?'isActive':'isNormal'" 
     (click)="selectThisOne('1')">
bla ...
</div>
```

in the ts-file:

```
selectThisOne(id: any) {
    this.cfgSelected = id;
}
```

it works in --dev but when I want to build --prod it I get

> ERROR in src\app\configurator\configurator.component.html(80,50): : Operator '===' cannot be applied to types 'number' and 'string'.

can someone please tell me what is wrong with that?

Comment: Make use of an integer instead, or at least parse it as such.

Comment: To add, the `===` operator doesn't cast the arguments to the same type, but if you used `==` it could work (but not best practice)

Answer (score 0):

Change `(cfgSelected ==='1')` to `(cfgSelected === 1)`

## Reason

Because `prod` does type checking